# Runtime exception thrown while using Pack URI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Trying to use Pack Uri in WPF project [dll].

Designer reflects the changes that I make to color style [Red, Blue etc. for background]
but during runtime, it throws an exception as below:

[image]

tried using:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Utils;component/Styles.xaml" />

<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Utils;component/Styles.xaml" />
```

but none worked.
What is wrong? I have Utils dll referenced in my current project.

Comment: Is `Styles.xaml` a top-level file in a project called `Utils`, and is that project referenced by the the project containing your `Window`?  Does `Styles.xaml` have a Build Action of "Page"?

Comment: Make sure Build Action as Resource and set Copy to Output Directory to false for Styles.xaml.

Comment: Yes Styles.xaml is the top-level file in Utils project. And Utils is referenced by Window project. I am also able to see the color change in designer window (like in the screenshot, red background. If I change color to blue in Styles.xaml, designer gets refreshed with blue background window)

Also,Copy to Output Directory set to > do not copy for Styles.xaml
and build action was Page initially, but even if I changed to Resource, it still complains with the same XAMLParsingException

Comment: Got it resolved!
Figured out there was some other issue with the project configuration.